# Programatic Notifications for "Find my iPhone"?

Tags: ios, iphone

When "Find my iPhone" is invoked, is there a way for an app running on the receiving phone to receive a notification that the event had occurred?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Find my iphone is an Apple service with no open documentation about the notifications and methods.